# How can you enable an ActiveX plugin via the registry? (IE8, Windows 7)

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, windows-7, activex, registry

At our enterprise we have an ActiveX plugin in IE that is currently disabled for at least some of the users.  I need to enable it for everyone, and I'm not sure but I think there's a way to toggle the disabled/enabled status for a plugin via the registry.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can push a script that will write your CLSID to:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Ext\PreApproved

...that should enable it.  For more details on ActiveX security wrt instantiation, see [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250471%28VS.85%29.aspx).

And don't forget to implement [IObjectSafety](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768224%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Also, if you're getting a specific error message, that info would help.